# Mutual authentication from JBoss 6 to JBoss 5.1.2

Tags: jboss

We would like to use mutual-authentication to secure a communication between a Java program running on Redhat JBoss 6 and a Java service running on Redhat JBoss 5.1.2. In other words, mutual-authentication where JBoss is both the client and the server. Is this possible? Some people say that JBoss Application Server can only handle the handshake if JBoss is at the role of the server only. Is this true? Thanks.

Comment: If server A connects server B (or the other way round), and both have to prove the other one's identity, you need something like a public/private key procedure. But this is not JBoss specific. Describe your participants further: What is your program running on JBoss 6 (servlet, ...)? Who is authenticating?

Comment: Hi Beryllium,thank you for your answer. Server A is a JBoss 6 running on RedHat Enterprise Edition. The application running on Server A is a Spring 3 application based on the servlet api. We would like the application or the container to authenticate itself to Server B running a java web service. I hope that I do not have to code the certificate-based PKI handshake on my application, but to configure JBOSS 6 to initiate the key handshake with JBOSS 5.1. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: That seems to be a normal werbservice client authentication against a webservice server (that's not mutual). AFAIK JBoss won't help here (it has nothing to do with JBoss on the client side). You should rephrase your question, add the code you have tried so far, and the problem you are facing.

Comment: Can the JBoss servlet container have the ability to initiate a mutual authentication connection on behalf of an application, like WebSphere can?  I understand that the JBoss application can, in fact, initiate that mutual authentication connection if the ability must be coded into the application. I don't know how else to ask the question. I want the container, not the application, to initiate the mutual-authentication.

Comment: I can't tell, if such an option is supported by JBoss.